# press home, then back to app and press back button,it exits the app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest file.

I am using google maps and on pressing the overlay -it opens a new intent.If I press back it comes back to the previous `activity`.

But if I *press home button and Hold Home button for few seconds and go back to my app and press back button* it exits the app.

> Summarizing -> GoogleMapsActivity -> DisplayActivity

here `GoogleMapsActivity` has `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in manifest file.hence I cannot go back to it.

Is there any possibility to send it to `GoogleMapsActivity` when *home button is pressed*  ,hence the activity would still exist. Or any other way to resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation? Check: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Yes Bandreid.I am trying to replicate the working of google maps it uses android:launchMode="singleInstance" but after I press home button and get back ,the activity still exists.Do you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the official documentation at:   [Manifest  element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and look at  `android:allowTaskReparenting` and `android:launchMode` 
sections.

Comment: I have added      android:launchMode="singleInstance"                     android:allowTaskReparenting="true" in GoogleMapsActivity,Still the above problem is not resolved.